# how to copy elements from one array to another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have function which randomly selects values from  `arrayVariable` and assingn them to paragraph element p[i].

I want to copy the randomly selected values to another array b[i].

How do i do it?

```js
function rvalue() {
  var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
  arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;

  ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
  for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
    ptags[i].innerHTML = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];

  }
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 2xpx;
  color: #000000;
 
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">
<p name="values"></p>
</div>
<p name="values"></p>
</div>
<p name="values"></p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem with current code? can you explain expected output?

Comment: create another array [] and push each arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)] into it

Comment: it works, iwant to make another array of the randomly selected values

Comment: so what would be the output you want for the code you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert text into an HTML element it is better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Create an array to push the `textContent` in each iteration:

```js
function rvalue() {
  var array = [];
  var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
  arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;

  ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
  for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
    ptags[i].textContent = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];
    array.push(ptags[i].textContent);
  }
  console.log(array);
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">

  <p name="values"></p>
  <p name="values"></p>
  <p name="values"></p>

</body>
```

Please Note: Your HTML has no opening `div` element and `font-size` has invalid value (2xpx).

Answer (score 0):

It will store value in `tempArray` by `index`, you can use Array.push for normal insert in replace of  `tempArray[index] = arrayVariable[index];`

```
tempArray.push(arrayVariable[index]);
```

and if you may get duplicate value in `array` if you use `.push` method then just use this code to remove duplicate entry

```
tempArray= tempArray.filter(function(val, i){
  return tempArray.indexOf(val)== i; 
});
```

```js
function rvalue() {
    var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
    arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;
    var tempArray = [];

    ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
    for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
        var index =
            Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength);
        ptags[i].innerHTML = arrayVariable[index];
        tempArray[index] = arrayVariable[index];

    }
    console.log(tempArray);
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 2xpx;
  color: #000000;
 
}
```

```html
<body onload="rvalue()">
<p name="values"></p>
</div>
<p name="values"></p>
</div>
<p name="values"></p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
function randomizeParagraphs() {
    var possibleValues = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        createdValues = [], // Empty array to store created values.
        pTags = document.getElementsByName("values");

    for (var i = 0; i < pTags.length; i++) {
        var item = possibleValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleValues.length)];
        ptags[i].innerHTML = item;
        createdValues.push(item);
    }

    // Log the created values.
    console.log(createdValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can assign get values like this,

```
function rvalue() {
  var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
  arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;

  arrRandomGeneratedValue = [];
  ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    randomGeneratedValue = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];
    ptags[i].innerHTML = randomGeneratedValue;
    arrRandomGeneratedValue.push(randomGeneratedValue);

  }
 return arrRandomGeneratedValue;
}

rvalue();
```

Answer (score 0):

well I dunno if I understood but if you want to save the random values use the push method in the new  array variable that you want to use as storage.

```
  function rvalue() {
  var b = [];
 var arrayVariable = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
 arrayLength = arrayVariable.length;

   ptags = document.getElementsByName("values");
   for (i = 0; i < ptags.length; i++) {
   ptags[i].innerHTML = arrayVariable[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayLength)];
   b.push(ptags[i].innerHTML);  
 }
 }
```

I hope that is what you were looking for :P 
regards!